# Simplify the following surd fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\dfrac{\sqrt{26 + \sqrt{675}} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{675}} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}} = \,?$$

I have simplified $$\sqrt{26 + \sqrt{675}} = \sqrt{\frac{27}2} + \sqrt{\frac{25}2}$$ and $$\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{675}} = 2 + \sqrt{3}.$$ E.g. For $$\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{675}}=\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt3}=a+b\sqrt3$$ and from this we equate integer parts of both sides and the coefficients of surd parts together finding $a$ and $b$.

However, I have a problem with the rest.

Comment: please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve readability of your question.

Comment: in denominator it should be 265 instead of 165

Comment: How did you simplify the cubic root? I am only taking your word for it, but I personally do not know. Is there a general formula to apply, possibly analogous for the square root you simplified?

Answer (score 1):

You have really done the hardest part

so, the expression reduces to

$$=\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{27}+5-(\sqrt{27}-5)}{\sqrt2}}{2+\sqrt3+2-\sqrt3}=?$$

Comment: but how did you find the second part of the denominator is 2-(3^1/2)

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi see my hint below :)

Comment: factors of 265 are 5 and 53(beside 1 a 265) . no it is not correct

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi sorry to say, but as a matter of fact, it is correct. I checked it using Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sqrt{26 \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{675}} = \sqrt{\frac{27}2} \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{\frac{25}2}$$ and $$\sqrt[3]{26 \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{675}} = 2 \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{3}.$$

(The double-signs are not independent of each other.)

Comment: @ Mr. Pie I was Commenting on lab bhattacharjee's solution  which I think is not correct. the procedure that I used for first parts of fraction can not be applied to second part because of 265 factors

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi The numerator is achieved by combining the two partial radical fractions into one whole fraction - I am not aware of factors being too involved. (I originally thought lab erred, incidentally, but I was mistaken.)

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi What precisely was your procedure on simplifying the surds?

Comment: @ Mr Pie for((26+(675^1/2))^1/3=((26+(15(3^1/2))^1/3=a+b(3^1/2)   from this we equate integer parts of both sides and the coefficients of surd parts together finding a and b.

Comment: @AhmadAhmadi ah, that's cool! Intuitively, a coefficient of $-15$ would bring forward $-b$ correspondingly, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that \begin{align}\dfrac{\sqrt{26 + \sqrt{675}} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{675}} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}} &= \dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{27}2} + \sqrt{\frac{25}2} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}}\end{align}

We can then simplify some of the surds in the numerator as follows

\begin{align}\sqrt{\frac{27}2}&=\frac{\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt2}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\\\\
\sqrt{\frac{25}2}&=\frac{\sqrt{25}}{\sqrt2}\\
&=\frac5{\sqrt2}\end{align}

Rewriting our main expression, this gives us \begin{align}\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{27}2} + \sqrt{\frac{25}2} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}}&=\dfrac{\frac{3\sqrt3}{\sqrt2} + \frac5{\sqrt2} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}}\\\\
&=\dfrac{3\sqrt3 + 5 - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{\sqrt{2}\left(2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}\right)}\tag{1}\\\\
&=\dfrac{3\sqrt3\sqrt2 + 5\sqrt2 - \sqrt2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{\sqrt2\sqrt{2}\left(2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}\right)}\tag{2}\\\\
&=\dfrac{3\sqrt6 + 5\sqrt2 - 2\sqrt{26 - \sqrt{265}}}{2\left(2 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{265}}\right)}\tag{3}\end{align}

where the steps are as follows:

1. Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt2$ to remove fractions in the numerator
2. Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt2$ again to neaten up the denominator (we could have combined steps 1 and 2 into simply multiplying top and bottom by $2$ however this is hard to spot in such a complex expression)
3. Simplify surds

Comment: @ ioness99a Thanks. But how do you simplify those expressions involving 265

Comment: They are already in their simplest form, as we can see using [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+sqrt%2826-sqrt%28265%29%29)